# Функция GetRegionData() всё время возвращает ноль! Как ей пользоваться, и что я неправильно делаю?

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Вот например:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HRGN hrgn = CreateEllipticRgn(100,300,800,500);
    RGNDATA data;
    if(!GetRegionData(hrgn,sizeof(data), &data)) MessageBox(0,"!","!",MB_OK);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Выводит на экран соответствующее сообщение.

Так тоже пробовал, результат такой же:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HRGN hrgn = CreateEllipticRgn(100,300,800,500);
    RGNDATA data;
    int i = GetRegionData(hrgn,0,0); // вроде должно возвр необходимое кол-во байт
    if(!GetRegionData(hrgn,i, &data)) MessageBox(0,"!","!",MB_OK);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Что мне делать, как мне быть? Вообще мне это нужно для вращения региона ( через ExtCreateRegion() ). Хочу разобраться.

Comment: может быть hrgn равно 0? В любом случае, неплохо получить результат вызова [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: подозреваю, что в хэлпе написано, что нужно заполнить первый член структуры, по которому, вероятно, определяется версия структуры. сам посмотреть не могу, но сужу по аналогии.

Answer (score 3):

Все как я и предполагал - структура заголовка содержит размер заголовка, который нужно заполнить: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162941(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162941(v=vs.85).aspx)

А вообще правильно советовали - пользуетесь кодом ошибки для того, чтобы получить ее текст (это можно сделать с помощью FormatMessage).

Comment: Можно на примере? Так я мало что понял)

Comment: @zer_ik, что не понятно?

   RGNDATA data;
   data.rdh.dwSize = sizeof(RGNDATAHEADER);
   if(!GetRegionData(hrgn,sizeof(data), &data)) MessageBox(0,"!","!",MB_OK);